# Is there a way to use a single setter for all properties?

Tags: javascript

Consider:

```
MyObject = {
    fruit:   'a',
    sweet:   'b',
    savoury: 'c',
    bitter:  'd'
};
```

Is there a way for a single JavaScript setter function to handle all of the properties or would I need to use my own setter function (as shown below)?

```
MyObject = {
    fruit:   'a',
    sweet:   'b',
    savoury: 'c',
    bitter:  'd',

    function set (name, value)
    {
        this[name] = value;
    }
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Proxy` to intercept any property name assignments:

```js
const MyObject = object({});

Object.assign(MyObject, {
    fruit:   'a',
    sweet:   'b',
    savoury: 'c',
    bitter:  'd'
});

function object(obj){

  const out = new Proxy(obj, {
  set(_, prop, val){
    if(Object.is(obj[prop], val)){
      return;
    }
    const oldValue = obj[prop];
    obj[prop] = val;
    console.log('change', prop,  ':', oldValue, '=>', val);
    return true;
    }
  });
  
  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up property descriptors for the object so that for each descriptor `get` and `set` delegate to central `get` and `set` methods, for example:

```js
function makeProps(obj, ...keys) {
    Object.defineProperties(obj, Object.fromEntries(
        keys.map(key => [
            key,
            {
                get: () => obj.get(key),
                set: val => obj.set(key, val)
            }
        ])
    ))
}

//


MyObject = {
    get(key) {
        return this['_' + key]
    },
    set(key, val) {
        console.log(`setting ${key} to ${val}`)
        this['_' + key] = val
    }
};

makeProps(MyObject, 'fruit', 'sweet', 'savoury', 'bitter')

MyObject.fruit = '123'
MyObject.bitter = '456'
```